# Need Help in Extjs for showing grid in panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I am very new to Extjs, I have a simple requirement such that if I will click on any of the leaf of the Tree on the left panel. I should see a grid in the right panel.
I got an [sample demo](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/layout-browser/layout-browser.html)

Here, for clicking to each of the leaf I should see a grid in Right Panel.

Please help, thanks in advance.

If you want to download a [quick application](http://s000.tinyupload.com/?file_id=03770664130174319165)

Answer (score 0):

Download Ext JS 4 (why not 5?). Unzip. Change dir to extjs\examples\layout-browser. Study layout-browser.js. e.g line 85. Oh i see your "quick application". So better visit the [how to start guide](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/up-and-running)
sorry for my stroppy reply